# Celluloid code testing approach

Tags: ruby, testing, celluloid

I spent some time googling subject however I've failed with this. Can somebody share any of the following?

- Example of *any async thing** with testing code written with `Celluloid`
- Article or even small write-up about testing async stuff in Ruby

---

* Sorry, I know `any async thing` sound weird, but I don't know how to call it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another question asked recently which demonstrates `asynchronous` processing:

- [Understanding Celluloid Concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061826/understanding-celluloid-concurrency)

What you're asking about is `asynchronous method calls` for `parallel` processing. It's not `concurrent` processing in the case above.

The terminology you are looking for is discussed in a video here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqnNCx7wVY